# "transformPoint" method on ARKit

Tags: transform, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, pose

There is a method from Android ARCore Pose() class.

```
pose.inverse().transformPoint()
```

I am looking for alternative of this on IOS platform (swift).
Does someone know about this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

ARKit has two useful methods:

> The first one helps project a point from the 3D world coordinate system of the scene to the 2D pixel coordinate system of the renderer.

```
func projectPoint(_ point: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3
```

> The second one helps unproject a point from the 2D pixel coordinate system of the renderer to the 3D world coordinate system of the scene.

```
func unprojectPoint(_ point: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3
```

Comment: thank you so much.
I used "transformPoint()" on Android for to convert Anchor points(pose) from a specific origin. Otherwise this line Anchors are shifting all the time so I make it this way. 
But IOS side unprojectedPoint() isn't about the touch points? 
For example I create an Anchor (zero point) and I need to convert all Anchors' pose to this zero point, this way no shifting or moving

Comment: Hi @Argos, in other words it doesn't suit you?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Answer (score 0):

I want to do like this way on ARKit - swift

```
 public static Vector3f TransformPointToPose(Vector3f point, Pose anchorPose) {
    // Recenter to anchor
    float[] position = new float[3];
    position[0] = point.x;
    position[1] = point.y;
    position[2] = point.z;
    

    position = anchorPose.inverse().transformPoint(position);
    return new Vector3f(position[0], position[1], position[2]);
}
```

and this is "transformPoint()" method in Pose class ARCore

```
  public float[] transformPoint(float[] var1) {
    float[] var2 = new float[3];
    this.transformPoint(var1, 0, var2, 0);
    return var2;
}
```

With all sub functions the pipeline like this;
[just a line - 91. line](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/justaline-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/arexperiments/justaline/rendering/LineUtils.java)

These are in the Pose Class

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]